# QGIS semi-automatic classification plugin - running into errors

Tags: qgis, scp

I'm trying to perform a classification on a large image. I've done one before but am having trouble processing this one. It's a maximum likelihood classification, and I'm getting the following errors in my log (sorry for the rushed post):

> ERROR|2024-03-25T16:19:26.805|band_classification|_get_x_y_arrays_from_rois|1535|Singular matrix

I've also seen covariance matrix errors on other ones. Any ideas how to resolve them? I'm using the latest SCP plugin and QGIS 3.34.